# remove space in the if statement

Tags: algorithms

[image]
I would like to remove the spaces within my if statement, how can I do that?

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
 \IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
 \usepackage{cite}
 \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
 \usepackage{algorithmic}
 \usepackage{algorithm}
 \usepackage{graphicx}

 \usepackage{textcomp}
 \usepackage{xcolor}
 \usepackage{multirow}
 \setlength{\textfloatsep}{0.1cm}

  \def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
  T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
 \begin{document}
  \begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Validation Algorithm}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \FORALL{r in Requirements}   
    \FORALL{m in Methods}   
    \item   OutputPredicted= TraceRefiner(r, m)
    \IF {m.GoldStandard[r]==m.Trace[r]}
    \IF {m.GoldStandard[r]==T}
    \RETURN TP   
    \ELSIF {m.GoldStandard[r]==N} 
    \RETURN TN
    \ENDIF
    \ELSE 
        \IF {m.GoldStandard[r]==N \AND 
        OutputPredicted.Value==T}
        \RETURN FP 
        \ELSIF {m.GoldStandard[r]==T \AND 
            OutputPredicted.Value==N}
        \RETURN FN
        \ELSE 
        \RETURN E  
         \ENDIF
    \ENDIF
    \ENDFOR
    \ENDFOR

\end{algorithmic}
\label{alg:ValidationAlgo}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make this a complete working example, i.e. something that people can compile as is.

Comment: I just did make such changes

Answer (score 1):

The big spaces occur because tex tries to justify the automatically wrapped lines. To avoid this add `\flushleft` before the algorithm:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
 \IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
 \usepackage{cite}
 \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
 \usepackage{algorithmic}
 \usepackage{algorithm}
 \usepackage{graphicx}

 \usepackage{textcomp}
 \usepackage{xcolor}
 \usepackage{multirow}
 \setlength{\textfloatsep}{0.1cm}

  \def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
  T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
 \begin{document}
  \begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Validation Algorithm}
  \flushleft
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \FORALL{r in Requirements}   
    \FORALL{m in Methods}   
    \item   OutputPredicted= TraceRefiner(r, m)
    \IF {m.GoldStandard[r]==m.Trace[r]}
    \IF {m.GoldStandard[r]==T}
    \RETURN TP   
    \ELSIF {m.GoldStandard[r]==N} 
    \RETURN TN
    \ENDIF
    \ELSE 
        \IF {m.GoldStandard[r]==N \AND 
        OutputPredicted.Value==T}
        \RETURN FP 
        \ELSIF {m.GoldStandard[r]==T \AND 
            OutputPredicted.Value==N}
        \RETURN FN
        \ELSE 
        \RETURN E  
         \ENDIF
    \ENDIF
    \ENDFOR
    \ENDFOR

\end{algorithmic}
\label{alg:ValidationAlgo}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image]